# Carousel Using ContentFlow.js Javascript 

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a cover flow style carousel with 7 images:

```
<!-- ===== FLOW ===== -->
<div id="contentFlow" class="ContentFlow">
    <!-- should be place before flow so that contained images will be loaded first -->
    <div class="flow">
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value1"><img class="content" src="image1.png"/></a>            
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value2"><img class="content" src="image2.png"/></a>            
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value3"><img class="content" src="image3.png"/></a>            
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value4"><img class="content" src="image4.png"/></a>            
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value5"><img class="content" src="image5.png"/></a>            
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value6"><img class="content" src="image6.png"/></a>            
            <a class="item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_value4"><img class="content" src="image7.png"/></a>            
    </div>
</div>
```

It utilizes this carousel cover flow: http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php

I want to have a separate div completely separate from the carousel that changes with the current content (clicks on each image).  Current content being the one in the middle that is the biggest (see website referenced above).  The following would be the divs that show up and disappear according to which item is active in the carousel.

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Need help with conceptualizing how I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

One place to start is to put your divs (div1, div2, div3) inside a div with the class caption. contentflow shows the unique caption with each active item, so the caption with your divs will change on each change in the active item ( no need to display:none):

```
<div class="item"> <img class="content" src="someImageFile.jpg"/> 
 <div class="caption">
 <div id="div1">Content1</div>
 <div id="div2">Content2</div>
 <div id="div3">Content3</div>
 </div> </div>
```